# IIS web app init sequence repeatedly crashing and restarting

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis, crash, startup

I'm working with an IIS-hosted ASP.NET service with very lengthy init sequence : hundreds of large xml files are loaded, parsed, cached, written to db, etc.

This past month the app began to occasionally endure an extremely lengthy init sequence, for example 30 mins versus normal time of 1 min. And this has been happening with higher frequency until now it happens on almost every startup.

Based on repeating log patterns, one possibility is that the app is terminated by Windows or IIS and then restarted. This repeats dozens of times, performing the init load sequence each time, until eventually startup succeeds.

Logs do not contain any errors ( no runtime exceptions thrown ) and this app has very good logging.

On what basis could Windows or IIS decide to kill the app pool process ( w3wp.exe ) ?  How can I further investigate the timestamps/intervals on which the app pool is restarted ?  What are some remedies to this issue ?

Comment: "I'm working with an IIS-hosted ASP.NET service with very lengthy init sequence : hundreds of large xml files are loaded, parsed, cached, written to db, etc." That already raises a red flag, as a web app should be responsive not only to browser view sizes, but also at request level. Otherwise, IIS/Windows health check would consider it a bad app and can terminate it. Application/System event log should tell what exactly you hit, as settings like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/failure should generate relevant log entries.

Comment: Redesign your web app so it starts and responds quickly, then such protection mechanism would leave it alone. Parallel programming is not hard, and you can also rip time consuming operations to an always running Windows service.